# If time slows down for the twin in the twin paradox why doesn't time change for us since we are accelerating around the sun?

Tags: general-relativity, time-dilation

I've just begun learning about relativity and I'm a little confused. While the rocket ship twin is traveling time only changes for them when they are accelerating, otherwise they are in an inertial frame and the physics works the same for them as it does for the twin on Earth. But aren't we accelerating here on Earth too? An object going in a circle or changing direction at all is accelerating, so that means that the Earth is accelerating. And if we are accelerating then we are no longer in an inertial frame so physics won't work the same for us.

Comment: It does. Every source of gravity (including the sun) has an effect on the proper time.

Comment: See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_dilation#Gravitational_time_dilation

Comment: @Alpha001 Does time slow down more for the twin because he is accelerating faster?

Comment: Yes, but not in the same amount

Comment: @ArmandoEstebanQuito What do you mean by "not in the same amount?"

Comment: i mean that time dilation rate by the sun is fixed, while the one on a spaceship can be made as large as you want by increasing the final  (cruise) speed

Comment: Yes. I'm not sure but as I remember the solution is also distance-dependent.

Comment: @Alpha001 Does both the sun's gravity and earth's gravity affect the time on a clock?

Comment: @Alpha001 yes, that is correct

Comment: have a look at theSR + GR corrections of the GPS positioning system http://www.astronomy.ohio-state.edu/~pogge/Ast162/Unit5/gps.html  "The combination of these two relativitic effects means that the clocks on-board each satellite should tick faster than identical clocks on the ground by about 38 microseconds per day (45-7=38)! "